# docker-machine with rsync

Tags: docker, rsync, docker-machine

I want to use `rsync` within order to synchronize a folder. `docker-machine` allows `rsync` with the `-d option`.

```
docker-machine scp -r -d . machine-name:~
```

This command seems to be working, however, I would like to extend the use of `rsync` to:

```
rsync -rvz --delete --exclude-from=.rsyncignore -e 'docker-machine ssh machine-name' . :
```

I also tried the following command:

```
sshpass -p "tcuser" rsync -rvz --delete --exclude-from=.rsyncignore  . docker@`docker-machine ip machine-name`:
```

Both command synchronize everything a first time, however, once everything is synced, I cannot access the VM anymore. If I try to access the VM through `docker-machine ssh machine-name` i receive the response`exit status 255`. What is happening?

Comment: wich type of permisions has you container shared (docker - machine) path ?

Comment: I'm not talking about containers since it's a docker-machine. Also, you mean most likely the permissions of the files within the directory I want to sync, which they could vary (read, write and execute) but the user owner is always the same.

Comment: you can execute command "docker ps -a" , and check if you machine id has changed ? maybe you need "docker-compose up -d", because your image has change

Comment: Please, i pray you to read it carefully. The docker machine is failing before running any container, it's during the synchronization of the files with the virtual machine that the problem is happening.

Comment: sorry, maybe your need check this tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.org/speed-up-file-access-in-docker-for-mac-fbeee65d0ee7

Answer (score 1):

You can find more about [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/speed-up-file-access-in-docker-for-mac-fbeee65d0ee7)

1.-The Dockerfile

```
 FROM centos:6
    # install rsync
    RUN yum update -y
    RUN yum -y install rsync xinetd
    # configure rsync
    ADD ./rsyncd.conf /root/
    RUN sed -i 's/disable[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*yes/disable = no/g' /etc/xinetd.d/rsync # enable rsync
    RUN cp /root/rsyncd.conf /etc/rsyncd.conf
    RUN /etc/rc.d/init.d/xinetd start
    RUN chkconfig xinetd on
    # create the dir that will be synced
    RUN mkdir /home/share
    # just to keep the container running
    CMD /etc/rc.d/init.d/xinetd start && tail -f /dev/null
```

2.-Build the container within the repository directory.

```
docker build . -t docker-rsync
```

3.-For start the container and map the rsync server port to a specific host port, like to

```
docker run -p 10873:873 docker-rsync
```

4.-Now we need to sync our share directory and sync any changes again as soon as anything changes. Rsync will only sync changes after an initial sync.

```
# initial sync
rsync -avP ./share --delete rsync://localhost:10873/example/
# sync on change
fswatch -0 ./share | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} rsync -avP ./share --delete rsync://localhost:10873/example/
```

UPGRADE: because docker machines change content and virtual disk need upgrade

first command when changed files in docker containers :

```
rsync --ignore-existing --sparse ...
```

second when docker machine create new files in containers sparse mode ,followed by:

```
 rsync --inplace ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I explained to you in the comments, I don't want to rsync to a container, I want to rsync to the virtual machine that is managed by docker-machine.

Comment: You use hyper-v or oracle virtual-box, or other ? and what OS works in

Comment: I'm working with `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` and the docker-machine is created with the virtualbox driver.

Comment: you probably check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox, and so this https://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer